# Group by 2 out of 3 columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

Using LINQ in C# you can group columns/properties like so:

```
group x by new { x.Column1, x.Column2, x.Column3 }
```

What if I want to group items if they match 2 out of the 3 properties? Is there a way to do that using LINQ?

The resulting grouping would look list this:

```
            Address          Zip         Id
Group 1      null           70002        78
Group 1      Main St        null         78
Group 1      Main St        70002       null

Group 2      Town Ln        null         15
Group 2      null           70006        15
Group 2      Town Ln        70006       null
```

Since two out of three match it would group them together, even if the last one was misspelled or missing.

Comment: What if you have an item that matches 2 properties in more than one group ? .. for example this object `{ Address = null, Zip = null, Id = null }` matches 2 properties in both `Group1` and `Group2`.

Comment: *Two out of three match* ... Each object you show has max 1 property in common with any other object. Sure, they have two properties in common with the properties found in their group, but then you have to find the groups before, erm... finding the groups.

Answer (score 1):

### Will IEnumerable.GroupBy() do?

I don't think a single `IEnumerable.GroupBy()` call alone can solve your problem here.

From [LINQ GroupBy documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The GroupBy(IEnumerable, Func)
>   method returns a collection of IGrouping objects, one
>   for each distinct key that was encountered.

Input data could be chosen in a way that some entries would have to end up in more than one group in result. This multiplication cannot happen in [current GroupBy implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs):

```
 internal static Lookup<TKey, TElement> Create<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (keySelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
        if (elementSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
        Lookup<TKey, TElement> lookup = new Lookup<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
        foreach (TSource item in source) {
            lookup.GetGrouping(keySelector(item), true).Add(elementSelector(item));
        }
        return lookup;
    }
```

Example of such input:

```
Id1 Zip1 Street1
Id1 Zip1 Street2
Id1 Zip2 Street1
```

this 3-item set would have to be grouped to a collection containing a total of 4 items:

```
Group 1: Id1 Zip1 Street1
Group 1: Id1 Zip1 Street2
Group 2: Id1 Zip1 Street1
Group 2: Id1 Zip2 Street1
```

### What could you use?

The specific case of match any 2 from 3 specific properties can obviously be solved by merging separate key GroupBys, removing duplicates and single rows already contained in larger sets. Not a single-liner, though.

You could also implement your own GroupBy function similarly to what's done in BCL, accepting a selector function generating multiple keys, and Lookup creator to add item to all groups. More work but you'd end up with prettier API.

Answer (score -1):

I solved in oracleSql by using calculated column. so for my case, the 1st variable was ok.
but 2nd column and 3rd , can be in one or other.
so what i did, I used case function, if column 2 is not null then value is : column 2, if null value is : Column 3.
so i guess , in your case, try to find equivalent for case function or if,
and u can generate 2 calculated columns.

case column 1 is null, var 1 = column2 and var 2 = column 3

case column 2 is null, var 1 = column1 and var 2 = column 3

case column 3 is null, var 1 = column 1 and var2 = column 3

then you can groub by var1 and var2